# Run a script every time a computer is created

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, azure-active-directory, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a script that moves computers to a specific OU every time they are created.
I have been researching about it, and I know that I can trigger a script with a scheduled task every time that the event log 4741 is created.
The thing is that, how can I get the computer name from this event log to include it in my script.

My script will be something like this:

```
if ('New computer name' -match '^ORD\d{3}$'){
Get-ADComputer "New computer name" | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=X,DC=X,DC=X"
}
```

I'm pretty confused hehe

Thanks in advice

---

Update:

I've been testing and I have written this command line:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4741 -Newest 1 | Select-Object -Property *
```

The only thing I need is to get the right property. The thing is that I can't get the SamAccountName as it's not a property per se. When i run this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4741 -Newest 1 | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName
```

I get an empty column.
I almost got it!

Comment: Most of the time you have to parse the event message to get those information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the newer [Get-WinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) cmdlet and parse out the information from the XML.

Try

```
# by default, Get-WinEvent returns event information in the order of newest to oldest.
foreach ($event in (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4741})) {
        # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
        $eventXml = ([xml]$event.ToXml()).Event
        # with this event, you can also parse out the 'TargetUserName' instead of 'SamAccountName'
        # if need be, you can get the computer SID using ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetSid' }).'#text'
        $computerName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'SamAccountName' }).'#text'
        if ($computerName -match '^ORD\d{3}$') {
            Get-ADComputer $computerName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=X,DC=X,DC=X"
            # you can exit the foreach loop here if you want with the break statement:
            # break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Theo! I have changed a bit the script, so I'm posting it in case somebody finds it usefull. I have changed the regex pattern, that's because computer's SamAccountNames have always a dollar sign in the end:

`$event = (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Security';ID=4741} -MaxEvents 1)
    $eventXml = ([xml]$event.ToXml()).Event
    $computerName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'SamAccountName' }).'#text'
    if ($computerName -match '^ORD\d{3}\$$') {
        Get-ADComputer $computerName | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=X,DC=X,DC=X"
    }`